# jquery - hide div on click body

Tags: jquery

I have a notification div that will popup if an user clicks .notification-popup. I am trying to do so the popop div will hide whenever an user clicks out side of that DIV.

Currently I have this:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('.notification-list-wrapper').each(function () {
                        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.notification-list-wrapper').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Although with this nothing even happens when I click the .notification-popup.

What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to prevent the click event propagation from the notification wrapper and hide the element on any other click

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $wrapper.hide();
});
var $wrapper = $('.notification-list-wrapper').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Another could be to test whether the click happened within the wrapper in the click handler

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest($wrapper).length == 0) {
        $wrapper.hide()
    }
});
var $wrapper = $('.notification-list-wrapper');
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds, darn :P